# How can I create a Excel Table using Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jexcelapi

I am using JExcel for creating an excel document. I want to create a Excel table in Excel document using JAVA. I have populated the rows and columns in cells, I could not able to create Excel table and populate data into Excel Table

Answer (score 3):

Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html), it has very good support for all types of Excel manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Very limited info but being thirsty for votes I will take a stab

Tables in excel are nothing but cells with boarders around them . Once you have data in your cells you use jxl.format.BorderLineStyle to create boarder around them and that would be your table . Simple :)

Comment: Ya i know that to populate the cells and putting borders arround them..but my requirement is to get the output excel document should have the data populated in ExcelTable.